# How can one stop becoming their own enemy?

Tags: vivekananda

As swami Vivekananda mentions if one doesn’t know how to control their mind then they themselves become their worst enemy. So how can one undo being their worst enemy , what are some practical methods to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Swami Ji's words seem to resonate with the Bhagavad Gita 6.5/6.6

> उद्धरेदात्मनात्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत् |
> आत्मैव ह्यात्मनो बन्धुरात्मैव रिपुरात्मन:
> **Elevate yourself through the power of your mind, and not degrade yourself, for the mind can be the friend and also the enemy of the self.**
> बन्धुरात्मात्मनस्तस्य येनात्मैवात्मना जित: |
> अनात्मनस्तु शत्रुत्वे वर्ते तात्मैव शत्रुवत्
> **For those who have conquered the mind, it is their friend. For those who have failed to do so, the mind works like an enemy**
> (Translation Swami Mukundananda)

> We are called upon to master the lower self (to know) the higher. The lower self is not to be destroyed. It can be used as a helper if it is held in check(commentary Sri. S Radhakrishnan)

But how ? Gita 2.41 seem to suggest a way .

The method is to strive for **vyavasayatmika buddhi** (in words of Gita) , ie. a resolute mind ,contrasted to a distracted mind , (a natural condition) that  subsists on endless desires , ever engaged in  pursuit of its fulfillment. The distracted mind is stated here to be the enemy, as it veils and projects.

> व्यवसायात्मिका बुद्धिरेकेह कुरुनन्दन।
> बहुशाखा ह्यनन्ताश्च बुद्धयोऽव्यवसायिनाम्।।2.41।।
> Here, in this path to Bliss there is only one thought of a resolute nature there is singleminded determination. This single thought arises from the right source of knowledge. The student of Yoga collects all the dissipated rays of the mind. He gathers all of them through discrimination, dispassion and concentration. He is free from wavering or vacillation of the mind.The worldlyminded man who is suck in the mire of Samsara has no singleminded determination. He entertains countless thoughts. His mind is always unsteady and vacillating.If thoughts cease, Samsara also ceases. Mind generates endless thoughts and this world comes into being. Thoughts, and names and forms are inseparable. If the thoughts are controlled, the mind is controlled and the Yogi is liberated(commentary Swami sivananda)

Karma/bhakti yoga is the path

> 1.12These thought-streams are controlled by practice and non-attachment.
> 1.13. Practice is the effort to secure steadiness.
> 1.14. This practice becomes well-grounded when continued with reverent devotion and without interruption over a long period of time.(Yoga sutras , Swami Vivekananda)

Answer (score 0):

they themselves become their worst enemy

- when they feel guilty of something done in the past.
- when they are in constant delimma and confusion.
- Obsessive Compulsive Thoughts

These things can be cured and undone

- Being aware of present moment.
- Gratitude
- Acceptance of what has happened and happening.
- Meditation - which just witnessing your thoughts.
- Love yourself unconditionally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much @raghu.